# Binary search in C always returns false, even when value is contained in sorted array

Tags: c, search

New to programming. Trying to implement binary search in C but unfortunately it isn't working properly. my function always returns false even when the value is in the array. New to programming. please help.

Function takes following inputs:
"value" - integer value to be found in array.
"values" - the sorted array.
"n" - number of integers in array.

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    // recursive implementation of binary search
    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        search_even(value, values, n);
    }
    else
    {
        search_odd(value, values, n);
    }
    return false;
}
bool search_even(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    // binary search
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // check middle of array
    else if (value == values[n/2])
    {
        return true;
    }
    // search left half of sorted array
    else if (value < values[n/2])
    {
        int less_than_arr[n/2];
        for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
        {
            less_than_arr[i] = values[i];
        }
        search(value, less_than_arr, n/2);
    }
    // search right half of sorted array
    else if (value > values[n/2])
    {
        int more_than_arr[(n/2) - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < (n/2) - 1; i++)
        {
            more_than_arr[i] = values[i + 1 + n/2];
        }
        search(value, more_than_arr, n/2);
    }
    return false;
}

bool search_odd(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    // binary search
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // check middle of array
    else if (value == values[n/2])
    {
        return true;
    }
    // search left half of sorted array
    else if (value < values[n/2])
    {
        int less_than_arr[n/2];
        for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
        {
            less_than_arr[i] = values[i];
        }
        search(value, less_than_arr, n/2);
    }
    // search right half of sorted array
    else if (value > values[n/2])
    {
        int more_than_arr[n/2];
        for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
        {
            more_than_arr[i] = values[i + 1 + n/2];
        }
        search(value, more_than_arr, n/2);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You don't need two separate functions for even and odd array lengths. In your code, `n/2` is an integer division that ensures that the result is a valid integer.

Comment: And you don't need to copy the subarrays to local arrays. Just use the input array. You are only reading, not modifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (recursively) call `search` functions but never return the value computed by the calls. Look at:

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    // recursive implementation of binary search
    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        search_even(value, values, n);
    }
    else
    {
        search_odd(value, values, n);
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function **always** return false.

You need at least to replace `search*(...)` with `return search*(...)`, so that value determined at the leaves of the calls is transmitted back to the original (first) call.

Answer (score 0):

Jean-Baptiste has already pointed out the obvious error in your function, but there are more issues:

You create local copies of the subarrays to search. This is not necessary and will make binary search slower than linear search.

Copying data is usually only necessary when you want to modify it, but retain the original state. Your search function only inspects the data. Strictly speaking, your argument `int values[]` should probably be `const int values[]` to reflect that fact.

In C, you must pass the pointer to the first element and the length of an array. Arrays decay into pointers to their first element, so the following:

```
int val[4] = {2, 4, 7, 12};

search(3, val, 4);
```

already does that.

But here's a useful idiom: If you want to pass in the subarray that starts at position `k`, use:

```
search(3, val + k, 4 - k);
```

More generally, you can pass the array slice `[lo, hi)`, where `lo` is the zero-based inclusive lower bound and `hi` is the exclusive upper bound as:

```
search(3, val + lo, hi - lo);
```

In the called function, the indices will then be `[0, hi - lo)`; the original array offset is lost.

Further, you don't need to distinguish the two cases of odd `n` and even `n` if you calculate the size of the right-hand array as difference between the original size minus the size of the left-hand array plus one:

```
mid == n / 2
left = [0, mid)
right = [mid + 1, n)
```

With this, your recursive binary search function will become:

```
bool search(int value, const int values[], int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return false;

    if (value < values[n / 2]) {
        return search(value, values, n / 2);
    }

    if (value > values[n / 2]) {
        return search(value, values + n / 2 + 1, n - n / 2 - 1);
    }

    return true;
}
```